# C++ class vs a library

Tags: c++, object, driver

Newbie here: I am looking at Arduino C++ driver code for some add-on hardware (camera, actuators, etc). The code defines a class which is then instantiated as an object  and sent commands by a user's program. Inside, the code is just procedural programming (e.g. it arduously "if-then" its way through many configurations rather inheriting from a base class or encapsulating algorithms).

I am left with the impression that the developers are just using a C++ class in place of a library and wondering what is the motivation to do so.  Is it easier for a novice user to copy the code and instantiate an object than to link to a library?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. Comparing objects and libraries, is like comparing apples and airplanes. They are entirely unrelated concepts. Perhaps there is a terminology problem here? Which C++ book are you using? Could you improve the question with a simple example?

Comment: this isn't a book but actual arduino code for a camera sensor configuration. they provide their driver as a C++ object. But it appears like a library of commands, services and configurations. so why not use a library instead?

Comment: Okay then, you know best. Good luck.

Comment: a library contains high level services which a user program interfaces to. it's compiles into the program as needed. an object has everything

Comment: yes, the hardware provides provides a class which is then instantiated as an object

Comment: ok, my apologies for the misleading title. i corrected it

Comment: Ok, after the edit it makes sense, but it's hard to say exactly why they do that. Perhaps the driver is supposed to be extremely customizable so they hand it over as-is to users to tweak it best they can - or they want to avoid the small overhead that comes with linking. I doubt it is to make it simpler for novices.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a facade pattern

Comment: Yes, technically you should be able to simply copy the sources into your project. But without seeing it can't say for sure.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/10461

Answer (score 1):

The term "library" is generally used for something that is written once and used  more than once, often by someone that is not its original author.

A "device driver" is generally used for a piece of software that handles the specifics of one device (a piece of hardware).

In most cases a device driver will be a library, but you could write a device driver specifically for one project as a class. The original author my have thought it easier for the  user to instantiate a class rather linking to a library.

A library can do more than handling a device, for instance a math library.